# Redirect Rules to allow html page to exist at directory url

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a directory called `/subject1/` which holds all subtopics inside of it such as `/subject1/subtopic1.html` , `/subject1/subtopic1.html` , `/subject1/subtopic1.html` and so on

I wanted to have a `/subject1.html` page as well but can't get the `.htaccess` to work as I rewrite the pages without `.html`  (also I broke my trailing slashes)

I have:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

and

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

and

```
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The issue is that right now it works for anything inside /subject1/subtopic1.html but for the page sitting at the directory location I get:

`/subject1.html -->301 --> /subject1  -->/subject1/`  which is the directory contents

Answer (score 0):

Change your 2nd rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```